# Show that for $n\in\mathbb N$ the mapping $f:M(n,\mathbb R)\to M(n,\mathbb R):A\mapsto A^n$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, matrices, metric-spaces, continuity, proof-verification

> **Show that for $n\in\mathbb N$ the mapping $f:M(n,\mathbb R)\to M(n,\mathbb R):A\mapsto A^n$ is continuous. ($M(n,\mathbb R)$ is identified with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ as a normed liner space.)**

$$\text{My attempt}$$

---

The result is true for $n=1$ since identity mapping is continuous. Let the result is true for all $n\le m$ for some $m\ge 1.$ We are to show that the result is true for $n=m+1.$

Choose $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}\in M(n,\mathbb R)$ and a sequence $\{A_k=(a_{ij}^k)_{n\times n}\}_{k=1}^\infty\subset M(n,\mathbb R)$ such that $A_k\to A.$ We shall show that $A_k^{m+1}\to A^{m+1}.$

By induction hypothesis, $A_k^m\to A^m$ as $k\to\infty.$ Let $A_k^m=(b^k_{ij}),~A^m=(b_{ij}).$

Then $b^k_{ij}\to b_{ij}$ and also $a_{ij}^k\to a_{ij}.$

So $\sum_{p=1}^n b_{ip}^k a_{pi}\to\sum_{p=1}^n b_{ip} a_{pi}^k\implies(\sum_{p=1}^n b_{ip}^k a_{pi})\to(\sum_{p=1}^n b_{ip} a_{pi}^k)\implies A_k^{m+1}\to A^{m+1}.$

Hence proved.

> - Is it a correct attempt?

Comment: What topology is used on $M(n,\mathbb R)$?

Comment: $M(n,\mathbb R)$ is identified with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ as a normed liner space.

Comment: Then a very simple argument seems to be: Every polynomial in $n^2$ variables is a continuous function on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.

Comment: Ya I knew that argument. Here I tried to make a different approach.

Comment: Another approach: take operator norm on $M(n, \mathbb{R})$. Then $|ABx| ≤ |A||Bx| ≤ |A||B||x|$. So $|AB| ≤ |A||B|$ and multiplication on $M(n, \mathbb{R})$ is continuous.

Comment: I'm yet to receive the response on the correctness of my approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the Sriti Mallick and Martin Sleziak's comments: $M(n,\mathbb R)$ is identified to $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ and $A^n$ is a polynomial in its $n^2$ components so we conclude that the given function $f$ is continuous.

There's a second method to prove the result: we have $f=g\circ h$ where 
$$h:M(n,\mathbb R)\to (M(n,\mathbb R))^n,\quad A\mapsto (A,\ldots,A) $$
and
$$g:(M(n,\mathbb R))^n\to (M(n,\mathbb R)),\quad (A_1,\ldots,A_n)\mapsto A_1\times\cdots\times A_n$$
moreover $h$ is clearly continuous and $g$ is continuous since it's a multilinear in a finite dimensional vector space so $f$ is continuous.